# android diasble EditText but not able to bring back to life

Tags: android, android-edittext

hi I am disabling an edittext during part of my program but later I want to bring it back on line, and its not accepting focus or text entry. here is the code

**Disable**

```
        intTextValue.setEnabled(false);
        intTextValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        intTextValue.setFocusable(false);
        intSeek.setEnabled(false);
        intType.setClickable(false);
```

**Enable**

```
        intTextValue.setEnabled(true);
        intTextValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        intTextValue.setFocusable(true);
        intSeek.setEnabled(true);
        intType.setClickable(true);
```

You will notice 3 variable names there intTextValue is the EditText, intSeek is a seek bar and intType is a spinner, the seekbar and spinner are both find, just editText which starts off enabled, after disable wont reenable.

help will be much appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: here you are disabling the click events of the spinner as intType.setClickable(false);.

Comment: are the `setInputType(NULL)` and `setFocusable(false)` really necessary?

Comment: I did read elsewhere that they could be, to be honest I've not tried without, but people have talked of problems with soft keyboard and track balls etc.. so wanted to play safe and just disable all. Not to distract from the main question though, disabling and reenabling more then I really need shouldn't cause  problems I think?

Comment: @Purplemonkey: try using this `setFocusableOnTouch()` instead of `setFocusable()`

Comment: hi imrankhan, this causes an error for me "The method setFocusableOnTouch(boolean) is undefined for the type EditText". I did however use the Eclipse help text and found setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean) and this works!! so thank you. thats the penultimate bug sorted, one to go :) p.s. you should add the answer to the main reply, and  i'll tick for you.

Comment: @Purplemonkey : see my answer i have add some more methods for disable/enable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

**Disable** :

```
EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editboxtxt);
        edt.setEnabled(false);
        edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        edt.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        edt.clearFocus();
```

**Enable** :

```
EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editboxtxt);
edt.setEnabled(true);
edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
edt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edt.requestFocus();
```